# How to select specific rows in PostgreSQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have written a query to get the 'reason_code' and 'app_count' for top five rows from result set and sum of remaining app_count under name 'others'.

Here what I have tried:

```
(SELECT a.app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd, a.denied_app_count
FROM (SELECT app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd ,COUNT(1) as denied_app_count
FROM app_pgm_choice, ead_case 
where app_pgm_sts= 'DN'
AND app_pgm_req_dt >= '20150101'
AND app_pgm_req_dt <= '20150130'
AND EAD_CS_APP_NUM =  APP_PGM_NUM
AND EAD_CS_SEND_CNTY_ID = '19'
AND EAD_CS_TRAN_STS = 'PE'
GROUP BY app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd
ORDER BY denied_app_count desc) a
WHERE ROWNUM <=5 )

UNION ALL

(SELECT 'OTHERS' as app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd, SUM(b.denied_app_count) as    denied_app_count
FROM (SELECT app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd ,COUNT(1) as denied_app_count
FROM app_pgm_choice, ead_case 
where app_pgm_sts= 'DN'
AND app_pgm_req_dt >= '20150101'
AND app_pgm_req_dt <= '20150130'
AND EAD_CS_APP_NUM =  APP_PGM_NUM
AND EAD_CS_SEND_CNTY_ID = '19'
AND EAD_CS_TRAN_STS = 'PE'
GROUP BY app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd
ORDER BY denied_app_count desc) b
WHERE ROWNUM >=5 )
```

But when I run this query it shows following error message:

> ERROR:  column "rownum" does not exist
>      LINE 13: WHERE ROWNUM <=5 )
>                ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: column "rownum" does not exist
>     SQL state: 42703
>     Character: 397

What is option for ROWNUM variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `LIMIT` clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometable 
ORDER BY denied_app_count DESC
LIMIT 5
```

`ROWNUM` is an Oracle-ism.

For greater-than, you can use `OFFSET`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometable 
ORDER BY denied_app_count DESC
OFFSET 5
```

to skip the first 5 rows and return the rest.

The two can be, and often are, combined when doing things like pagination.

See [`LIMIT` and `OFFSET`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html)

In PostgreSQL you *can* use the `row_number()` window function, but for your purpose here it's unnecessary. On the other hand, it might be *faster* to do a single query with `row_number` then query the result table twice to get the two parts. Try that approach and see if it performs better.

Comment: But how can I select LIMIT for selecting rows with rownum >5 ?

Comment: Yeah. This is amazing. It's not even making my query complex. Looks Good Now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
(SELECT a.app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd, a.denied_app_count
FROM (SELECT app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd ,COUNT(1) as denied_app_count
,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd ) AS ROWNUM 
FROM app_pgm_choice, ead_case 
where app_pgm_sts= 'DN'
AND app_pgm_req_dt >= '20150101'
AND app_pgm_req_dt <= '20150130'
AND EAD_CS_APP_NUM =  APP_PGM_NUM
AND EAD_CS_SEND_CNTY_ID = '19'
AND EAD_CS_TRAN_STS = 'PE'
GROUP BY app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd
ORDER BY denied_app_count desc) a
WHERE ROWNUM <=5 )

UNION ALL

(SELECT 'OTHERS' as app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd, SUM(b.denied_app_count) as    denied_app_count
FROM (SELECT app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd ,COUNT(1) as denied_app_count
,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd ) AS ROWNUM 
FROM app_pgm_choice, ead_case 
where app_pgm_sts= 'DN'
AND app_pgm_req_dt >= '20150101'
AND app_pgm_req_dt <= '20150130'
AND EAD_CS_APP_NUM =  APP_PGM_NUM
AND EAD_CS_SEND_CNTY_ID = '19'
AND EAD_CS_TRAN_STS = 'PE'
GROUP BY app_pgm_rsnd_rsn_cd
ORDER BY denied_app_count desc) b
WHERE ROWNUM >=5 )
```

Comment: Its showing this error: ERROR:  column "denied_app_count" does not exist

Comment: Super. This works. Thanks :). Can you please add some description to your answer. What you did and all?

Comment: If it is help out then given right mark and also given vote

Comment: @MukeshKalgude It's really a good idea to *explain why* where possible. (I don't upvote code-only answers, btw).